# Riemann Prime numbers less than a given quantity

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-zeta

In Riemann's Paper *On the Number of Prime Numbers less than a Given Quantity* he states the Euler Product

$\prod\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p^s}}=\sum\frac{1}{n^s}$

"Where if one substitutes for $p$ all prime numbers, and for n all whole numbers. The function of the complex variable a which is represented by these two expressions, wherever they converge, I denote $\zeta(s)$. Both expressions converge only when the real part of $s$ is greater than 1." This is from the paper.

He then uses the equation

$$\tag{1}\int_0^\infty e^{-nx}x^{s-1}dx=\frac{\prod(s-1)}{n^{s}} $$

$$\tag{2}{\prod(s-1)}\zeta(s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^{x}-1}dx$$

My question is how goes from equation 1 and 2 and was wondering if anyone could explain it.

Thanks me

Comment: A summation would do the job, if you are asking why eq. (1) implies eq. (2).

Answer (score 2):

You sum both sides of the equality $(1)$:\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-nx}x^{s-1}\,\mathrm dx&=\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nx}x^{s-1}\,\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}x^{s-1}\,\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^\infty\,\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}\mathrm dx\end{align}and$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\Pi(s-1)}{n^s}=\Pi(s-1)\zeta(s).$$

Comment: why does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nx}$ go to $\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}$?

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nx}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(e^{-x})^n=\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}$$